# org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, amazon-web-services, java-8

I am using Java 8, Hibernate 5.1 and eclipse its working fine when using java code but when I setting proxy in java code or passing as VM argument in eclipse to connect AWS Cloud then hibernate connection get failed.
Java code which I setting proxy.

```
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "comproxy.net");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
System.setProperty("http.nonProxyHosts", "localhost|127.0.0.1");
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "tm_user");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password@135");
```

or VM argument

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
-Dhttp.proxyHost=comproxy.is
-Dhttp.proxyPort=80
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost
-Dhttp.proxyUser=tm_user
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=pwd@135
```

Exception

```
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 10 (min=1)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
    at com.singtel.mi.database.MIQueueDaoImpl.getSessionFactory(MIQueueDaoImpl.java:67)
    at com.singtel.mi.database.MIQueueDaoImpl.openCurrentSession(MIQueueDaoImpl.java:44)
    at com.singtel.mi.service.MessageInboxService.findAllCampaign(MessageInboxService.java:66)
    at com.singtel.mi.service.APICallService.postJSONDatatoAWS(APICallService.java:25)
    at com.singtel.mi.service.TestMessageInbox.main(TestMessageInbox.java:8)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:161)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:273)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:318)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:147)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:31)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:545)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38)
    ... 32 more
```

Its failing because of proxy setting or  `-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true` or because of cloud?

```
public class HibernateUtil {

  private final static SessionFactory sessionFactory;
  //private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  static{
    try {   
      sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/com/singtel/mi/utils/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Seesion Factory Creation Failed---> "+e);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError();
    }
  }

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

I am not able to get root cause for this.

Comment: Check the hostname and port of the proxy server. Even in your question, you are using two different host names.

Comment: Hi @Holger, thanks for reply its type mistake both host is same. I am connecting DB using **Hibernate5.1** and after get record posting data on AWS cloud using **HttpURLConnection** The problem is at a time only one connection is happening. Ex if i connect DB with hibernate then AWS connection failing if firstly i will connect AWS then i am getting above stack trace, i am always starting new connection and close all session before jumping from DB connection to AWS or AWS to DB.

Comment: Maybe a proxy limitation?

Comment: Interesting: what kind of proxy limitation if elaborate more it will help to understand more. Even today i am trying with JDBC and getting error          `java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection` i feel some resource getting engaged by one connection and not releasing for another kind of connection.

Comment: Well, the maximum number of connections could be set to one.

Comment: i received this error when i gave incorrect db username/password